# Simple ODS, OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space on save file

Tags: java, spring, export, ods

I get this error "OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space", when save a file with 1500 rows or more.

I try solve this split the list data

I tried to solve this split data list into smaller parts and save and load the ods file. I use de function insertRowsBefore to append new rows. But its not work for me. When save load the table, append new row list and save, the save function save a full table again and I get the error. My rows has thirty-five columns

I try to use this versions:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.odftoolkit</groupId>
<artifactId>simple-odf</artifactId>
<version>0.6.6</version>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.odftoolkit</groupId>
<artifactId>simple-odf</artifactId>
<version>0.7-incubating</version>
</dependency>
```

Error details:

```
13:45:12,821 INFO [stdout] Excepción: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space 
13:45:12,822 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2271) 
13:45:12,822 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:113)
13:45:12,822 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
13:45:12,822 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:140)
13:45:12,823 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
13:45:12,823 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:282)
13:45:12,823 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125) 
13:45:12,823 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:207)
13:45:12,823 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:127)
13:45:12,824 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at org.apache.xml.serialize.Printer.printText(Unknown Source)
13:45:12,824 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at org.apache.xml.serialize.XMLSerializer.printAttribute(Unknown Source)
13:45:12,824 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at org.apache.xml.serialize.XMLSerializer.serializeElement(Unknown Source) 
13:45:12,824 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at org.apache.xml.serialize.BaseMarkupSerializer.serializeNode(Unknown Source) 
13:45:12,824 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at org.apache.xml.serialize.XMLSerializer.serializeElement(Unknown Source) 
13:45:12,824 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at org.apache.xml.serialize.BaseMarkupSerializer.serializeNode(Unknown Source) 
13:45:12,825 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at org.apache.xml.serialize.XMLSerializer.serializeElement(Unknown Source) 
13:45:12,825 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at org.apache.xml.serialize.BaseMarkupSerializer.serializeNode(Unknown Source) 
13:45:12,825 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at org.apache.xml.serialize.BaseMarkupSerializer.serializeNode(Unknown Source) 
13:45:12,825 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at org.apache.xml.serialize.BaseMarkupSerializer.serialize(Unknown Source) 
13:45:12,826 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at org.apache.xml.serialize.DOMSerializerImpl.write(Unknown Source)
13:45:12,826 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.OdfPackage.flushDom(OdfPackage.java:1626)
13:45:12,826 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.OdfPackage.getBytes(OdfPackage.java:1566)
13:45:12,826 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.OdfPackage.save(OdfPackage.java:877)
13:45:12,827 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.OdfPackage.save(OdfPackage.java:823)
13:45:12,827 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at org.odftoolkit.simple.Document.save(Document.java:728) 
13:45:12,827 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at org.odftoolkit.odfdom.pkg.OdfPackageDocument.save(OdfPackageDocument.java:228)
```

Log for my custom functions and services

```
13:45:12,828 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
13:45:12,828 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
13:45:12,828 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
13:45:12,828 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) | java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space 
13:45:12,828 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2271)
13:45:12,828 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:113)
13:45:12,828 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
13:45:12,828 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:140)
13:45:12,828 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
13:45:12,829 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:282)
13:45:12,829 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
13:45:12,829 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:207)
13:45:12,829 INFO [stdout] (asyncExecutor-1) at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:127)
```

My export code:

```
public static <T> void export(String[] columnTitle, List<T> data, String[] fields, String path, String filename) throws Exception {

    try {
        SpreadsheetDocument ods = SpreadsheetDocument.newSpreadsheetDocument();
        ods.removeSheet(0);

        Table table = Table.newTable(ods, data.size() + MagicNumber.TWO, columnTitle.length, 0, 0);
        table.setTableName(filename);
        String[] values = new String[fields.length];
        int line = 0;

        Border border = new Border(Color.BLACK, BORDER_WIDTH, StyleTypeDefinitions.SupportedLinearMeasure.PT);

        List<Row> rows = table.getRowList();

        Row r = rows.get(line);
        Cell cell = r.getCellByIndex(0);

        //Style for column title
        Font font = new Font(ARIAL_FONT, FontStyle.BOLD, MagicNumber.SEVEN, Color.BLACK);
        r = rows.get(line);
        for (int a = 0; a < fields.length; a++) {
            cell = r.getCellByIndex(a);
            cell.setStringValue(columnTitle[a]);
            cell.setBorders(CellBordersType.ALL_FOUR, border);
            cell.setCellBackgroundColor(Color.valueOf("#A5A5A5"));
            cell.setFont(font);
            cell.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignmentType.CENTER);
        }

        //write data
        font = new Font(ARIAL_FONT, FontStyle.REGULAR, MagicNumber.SEVEN);
        for (T obj : data) {
            line++;
            r = rows.get(line);
            for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
                cell = r.getCellByIndex(i);
                values[i] = getProperty(obj, fields[i]);
                cell.setStringValue(String.valueOf(values[i]));
                cell.setBorders(CellBordersType.ALL_FOUR, border);
                cell.setFont(font);
                cell.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignmentType.RIGHT);
            }
        }

        //Error with 2000 results
        ods.save(path);

    } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
        LOG.error(e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error(e);            
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post code samples? It is much easier to help with the problem if we can see your code.

Comment: edit with my custom export code @slarge

Comment: What does getProperty(obj, fields[i]) do? What does it retrieve? I wrote 20000 lines no problem is my own example Class based on yours.

Comment: Get the value of the property of the object. Can it be for using an asynchronous method? @slarge

Comment: Are you using any format cells? thanks @slarge

Comment: I copied your code and tweaked to get it working.

Comment: I call the method to export from an asynchronous method, with "@Async" annotation. Can you you try this? @slarge

Answer (score 0):

I had to write 200000 rows before getting an GC OutOfMemory error.

To fix this I added a save every 1000 rows (SAVE_POINT below) in the for loop

```
for (T obj : data) {
    line++;
    r = rows.get(line);

    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        cell = r.getCellByIndex(i);
        values[i] = getProperty(obj, fields[i]);
        cell.setStringValue(String.valueOf(values[i]));
        cell.setBorders(CellBordersType.ALL_FOUR, border);
        cell.setFont(font);
        cell.setHorizontalAlignment(HorizontalAlignmentType.RIGHT);
    }

    if ((line % SAVE_POINT) == 0) {
        ods.save(path + filename);
    }

}
```

I have read in a few forums that say simple-odf isn't very good with large spreadsheets so maybe try another library like POI if you have any further problems.

Comment: I read that too but I need generate a ods file. Your code has the same problem. I tried to save every 1000 rows. I load the file and use insertRowsBefore to append new rows. But the component simple-ods load the existing file, append new rows and save all again. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah you are right. I'm not getting any errors on my code now even if I write 300k. You may need to write, close and reopen the file and write in batches.

Comment: How many columns per row you are writing? I have 35 columns. If I delete cell formatting rows I can wrote 5000 rows without error. But still much difference. The error is not the same. Your mistake is GC OutOfMemory and mine is Java heap space

Comment: Yes I recreate a heap space so think the GC error was due to running other things in my IDE. I am only writing 1 column.